# C#'s/Java's List<Type> data structure in JQuery/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, list

Is there any way to create a List of objects in JS/JQuery as I do in C#?

I just want to dynamically add objects to a list as I do in C#. Like:

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>();
myList.add("myString");
```

Is there any way to achieve the same thing in Javascript? I don't care if the list is typed or not. I just want the data structure.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use an array.

Example:

```
var myList = [];
myList.push("myString");
```

In C# arrays are fixed size, but in Javascript you can add items to them just like lists in C#.

Comment: If you really must have a similar api you can make a wrapper for this code that has some/all of the same methods as the c# implementation which would just modify the array internally.

Comment: Thanks a ton! Simple question, simple answer.